# NewRelic for .NET needs COR_ENABLE_PROFILING set to 1 in registry

Tags: .net, iis, registry, newrelic

I just installed the NewRelic .NET agent on our test server.  I got an error saying that the installer was **unable to access the registry** and that **COR_ENABLE_PROFILING needs to be set to 1** before the agent will work.

How can I set COR_ENABLE_PROFILING to 1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a System Environment variable COR_ENABLE_PROFILING and set the value to 1 and restart server just in case.

Comment: I will upvote your answer if you add step-by-step instructions on how to create a sysenv variable, for those who don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is resolved but just in case: a few recent changes to the New Relic's .NET agent have improved how this setup works, so installing the newest version will also generally fix this issue (re-running the installer can as well). If you're still having trouble, I'd strongly recommend opening a ticket at https://support.newrelic.com/

Answer (score 0):

New version of new Relic creates a system variable, but in my case that didnt work so I created a new "user eviroment variable" with the same value.

To create a environment variable you have to go to the My computer> Advanced system settings

In the System Properties window select Advanced tab and click on Environment Variables…

In the Environment Variables window you will notice two columns User variables for a username and System variables.

Probably you already have the System variable, but you need to create a new User variable with the same parameter COR_ENABLE_PROFILING and set the value to 1.

I hope this work for you.
And Im sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of the New Relic agent for .NET place necessary environment variables in the Registry.  System environment variables (those accessed from System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables) are only needed if you plan to monitor non-IIS apps.  They are created when you install the .NET agent with the "Instrument All .NET Applications" option enabled.

It sounds like the original problem related to permissions issues adding values to the Registry.